# Permission denied error installing rpart.plot package in R

Tags: r

Hello when I try to install rpart.plot package in R I receive the following error

> Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/hp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/file220c4f062ad7/Formula/doc/Formula.pdf': Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a dependency problem. The rpart.plot package depends on pkg:'earth' and it in turn depends on pkg:Formula. Unfortunately,  the `install.packages` function doesn't construct a search path for this situation and simply reports an error if the second-level dependency is not present. So do this:

```
install.packages("Formula", dependencies=TRUE)
Install.packages("rpart.plot",  dependencies=TRUE)
```